# Search users in a group - Jetty JAAS LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, jetty, openldap, jaas

I am using Jetty's [LDAP Login Module](https://eclipse.dev/jetty/javadoc/jetty-9/org/eclipse/jetty/jaas/spi/LdapLoginModule.html) to connect to an internal LDAP server. The **LDAPLoginModule** configuration (`ldap-loginModule.conf`) is provided as below:

```
ldap {
   org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.LdapLoginModule required
   debug="true"
   contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
   hostname="<ldap hostname>"
   port="389"

   bindDn="cn=admin,dc=myorg,dc=com"
   bindPassword="password"
   authenticationMethod="simple"
   forceBindingLogin="true"

   userBaseDn="ou=users,dc=myorg,dc=com"
   userRdnAttribute="cn"
   userIdAttribute="cn"
   userPasswordAttribute="userPassword"
   userObjectClass="inetOrgPerson";
};
```

The above code works fine when I integrate it with my application, using the JVM parameter:
`-Djava.security.auth.login.config=./ldap-loginModule.conf`. As you can understand, the above LDAP configuration searches through **all** of the users in the `userBaseDN`(ou=users,dc=myorg,dc=com).

However, I am searching for users with a specific `role` (`cn=my-group,ou=roles,dc=rsorg,dc=com`) using the above configuration.? I am looking for a solution which would replicate the below ldap search in the above JETTY LDAP configuration:

```
ldapsearch -x -H ldap://<ldap hostname>:636 -b "dc=myorg,dc=com" -D "cn=admin,dc=myorg,dc=com" -w password "(&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(memberOf=cn=my-group,ou=roles,dc=rsorg,dc=com))"
```

Below is the configuration, I have tried and it didn't fetch me the correct result:

```
 ldap {
   org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.LdapLoginModule required
   debug="true"
   contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
   hostname="<ldap hostname>"
   port="389"

   bindDn="cn=admin,dc=myorg,dc=com"
   bindPassword="password"
   authenticationMethod="simple"
   forceBindingLogin="true"

   userBaseDn="ou=users,dc=myorg,dc=com"
   userRdnAttribute="cn"
   userIdAttribute="cn"
   userPasswordAttribute="userPassword"
   userObjectClass="inetOrgPerson"

   ## Additional role check
   roleBaseDn="cn=my-group,ou=roles,dc=myorg,dc=com"
   roleNameAttribute="cn"
   roleMemberAttribute="memberOf"
   roleObjectClass="groupOfUniqueNames";
};
```

I am using OpenLDAP to configure the LDAP and the application is a JAVA application.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for you, [Jetty's module source code](https://github.com/jetty/jetty.project/blob/jetty-10.0.x/jetty-jaas/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/jaas/spi/LdapLoginModule.java#L547) has an hardcoded ldap filter:

```
String filter = "(&(objectClass={0})({1}={2}))";
```

Where `{1}` will be replaced by the value `userIdAttribute` and `{2}` the username of the user trying to log in.

You can play some tricks by "injecting" (as in SQL injection) your search query in the `userIdAttribute` parameter. Usual caveats about parameter abuse apply here, obviously.

I cannot test it, but I would try to set `userIdAttribute` to this value:

```
userIdAttribute="memberOf=cn=my-group,ou=roles,dc=rsorg,dc=com)(cn"
```

So that at runtime the search becomes (with `{2}` still the username):

```
(&(objectClass={0})(memberOf=cn=my-group,ou=roles,dc=rsorg,dc=com)(cn={2}))
```

Same thing, in color:
[image: LDAP search filter injection]

Explained [here](https://piellardj.github.io/ldap-filter-analyzer/?input=%28%26%28objectClass%3D%7B0%7D%29%28memberOf%3Dcn%3Dmy-group%2Cou%3Droles%2Cdc%3Drsorg%2Cdc%3Dcom%29%28cn%3D%7B2%7D%29%29)